# C# Active Directory Application is lagging when filling the textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, active-directory, ldap

I am on a mission to create an ultimate application that would communicate with the active directory and get all the current users. we are maintaining a old excel sheet with all the new users the problem with that is when anyone leaves the organization they are not removed, so new users get added but the old users stay in the excel sheet as well, causing growth of the excel sheet, so now the management wants to
have a desktop application that they can use to search user and get his/her information but my application is lagging, for example user john is selected, john's phone number is displayed 123-456-7890 now i select the last user in the drop down Joe and all the information changes but the phone textbox still hold the values 123-456-7890. how what am i doing wrong here and any suggestions or workaround would be much appreciated.

```
 private void ShowUserInformation(SearchResult rs)
    {
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
            username.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value != null)
            FirstName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value != null)
            MiddleName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value != null)
            LastName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value != null)
            email.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["personalTitle"].Value != null)
            title.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["personalTitle"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value != null)
            company.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value != null)
            city.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["st"].Value != null)
            state.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["st"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value != null)
            country.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memeberOf = IS Team"].Value != null)
            Groups.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memeberOf = IS Team"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value != null)
            postalcode.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
            phone.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["streetAddress"].Value != null)
            address.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["streetAddress"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value != null)
            department.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value != null)
            descriptions.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeID"].Value != null)
            employee.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["employeeID"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mobile"].Value != null)
            mobile.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mobile"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["accountExpires"].Value != null)
            accountexpires.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["accountExpires"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDrive"].Value != null)
            homedrive.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDrive"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value != null)
            homedirectory.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value != null)
            WhenCreate.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogoff"].Value != null)
            lastloggedoff.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lastLogoff"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["badPasswordTime"].Value != null)
            badpassword.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["badPasswordTime"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value != null)
            WhenCreate.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenChanged"].Value != null)
            whenchanged.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenChanged"].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds likely that the second user you select does not have a phone number set, and thus it is not updating the field. Can you put a breakpoint on this line:

```
if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value != null)
        email.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
```

and see if their `mail` property is really set?

Comment: Yes added a breakpoint and the mail property is set and for each user the mail property is changing, so like your saying if a user does not have a phone number it doesn't get updated hence we are looking at the value from the previous user but i even did that check if i select a user with no phone number the textbox value is blank and then select a user if the phone number the value changes, it only lags when the selection range is lot greater for example select the first user, immediately selecting the last user throws it off.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix the textbox vaules that are lagging i just added an else statement, that did the trick.

```
    if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
            phone.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
    else phone.Text = "";
```